# Partial application is not allowed while using Function

Tags: coq

I get the following error message:

```
"failure in proveterminate Error: Partial application of function convert_btree_to_tree in its body is not allowed while using Function"
```

from the following piece of Coq script, but I have no idea what is wrong. Can anyone give me some advice?

```
Function convert_btree_to_tree (t: btree (non_terminal' non_terminal terminal) terminal) {measure (fun t => bheight _ _ t)}: 
tree (non_terminal' non_terminal terminal) terminal:=
let tl:= decompose t in
let ttl:= map convert_btree_to_tree tl in
let ttl':= convert_list_tree_to_tree_list ttl in
match broot _ _ t with
| inl n => node _ _ n ttl'
| inr t => node_t _ _ t
end.
```

Documentation on Function is very limited in the Reference Manual, does anybody know of a more complete and detailed reference, if possible with comments and examples?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `Function` but in your `match`, you return a `node` and a `node_t`. Since you didn't give the definitions, I don't know if these two constructors are from the same type, but I think you have a typo and the second case should return `node t _ _ t`.

EDIT after feedback from Marcus:
`node_t` is a constructor of `tree` which signature is `terminal -> tree`: given a term `foo` of type `terminal`, `node_t foo` is of type tree. `node` has the signature `non_terminal -> tree_list -> tree`.

Do you have any implicit parameters declared ? Otherwise, in your `match` cases, you apply too many arguments to `node` and `node_t`, which might be interpreted as partial application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I didn´t mention that, but yes, they are of the same type. The definition is:

    Inductive tree: Type:=
    | node_t: terminal -> tree
    | node_n: non_terminal -> tree 
    | node  : non_terminal -> tree_list -> tree
    with tree_list: Type :=
    | tl_nil : tree_list
    | tl_cons: tree -> tree_list -> tree_list.